# template overloading plus pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, templates, constants, overloading

I have the following code:

```
template<class A, class B>
void test(A& a, const B* b)
{ std::cout << "hi" << std::endl; }

template<class A, class B>
void test(A& a, const B** b)
{ std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }

class TestClass
{};


int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    TestClass b;
    TestClass* c = &b;
    test(a, &c);
    return 0;
}
```

Somehow the output is "hi" although it seems that better match would be the second template function. When I remove `const`s as the qualifiers to `B*` and `B**` then I get "hello" which corresponds to the second template function. How does the compiler choose the function to call in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers correctly note that there is no implicit conversion from `T**` to `const T**` and therefore one of the overloads is not viable at all. I'll explain why this conversion is not allowed. It is actually written as an example in the standard. To quote paragraph 4.4,

> [ Note: if a program could assign a pointer of type T** to a pointer
>   of type const T** (that is, if line #1 below were allowed), a program
>   could inadvertently modify a const object (as it is done on line #2).
>   For example,

```
int main() {
    const char c = ’c’;
    char* pc;
    const char** pcc = &pc; // #1: not allowed
    *pcc = &c;
    *pc = ’C’; // #2: modiﬁes a const object
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that there is no conversion from `T**` to `T const**` the second isn't a match at all (there is no such conversion because it would allow non`const` access to a `const` object). There is a conversion from `T**` to `T* const*`, however. Thus, the corresponding overload is the only viable and used one.

Answer (score 3):

`&c` is a `TestClass**` which may be promoted to `TestClass* const *` but not to `const TestClass**`.

You may force the error by explicitly using `test<int, TestClass>(a, &c);` which will show you the impossible conversion.